# Indicadores para funciones

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la siguiente consulta, tengo 2 modales un editar y otro agregar el problema es cuando abro el editar me sale con todos los campo llenos de acuerdo a la row que seleccione y cuando quiero abrir el modal de agregar me sale con todo los datos llenos. Cabe recalcar que solo hay 1 modal para ambos lo que los diferencia solo es el titulo.

Me sugirieron colocar un indicador para diferenciar el uno del otro. Alguien me podria explicar y ayudar en esto. Gracias

```
<button onclick='modoNuevoPH();' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalAgregarModificarPIS' data-backdrop='static' data-keyboard='false' id="" class="btn btn-linecyan"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Nuevo Grupo Especializado</button>

function modoNuevoPH() {
    $('#tituloAgregarModificarPIS').html("<span>Nuevo Puntos de Ingreso/Salida</span>");
    $('button.close').prop('disabled', true).css('display', 'none');
    $('.modal-footer').show();
};

 $("#tablaConsultaPis").on('click', '.editar-punto-ingreso', function() {
            var _tr = $(this).closest('tr'); // Toma el primer "tr" que encuentre
            var data = $("#tablaConsultaPis").DataTable().row(_tr).data(); // Toma toda la fila

            $('#tituloAgregarModificarPIS').html("<span>Editar Puntos de Ingreso/Salida</span>");
            $('button.close').prop('disabled', true).css('display', 'none');
            $('.modal-footer').show();

            $('#txtNumRUCModal').val($.trim(data.rucPuntoHab));
            $('#txtCodPISModal').val($.trim(data.codPuntoHab));
            $('#txtDireccionModal').val($.trim(data.dirPuntoHab));    
            $('#txtNumUbigeoModal').val($.trim(data.ubiPuntoHab));          

            $('#fechaInicial').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                language: 'es',
                updateViewDate: false
            });

            $("#fechaInicial").datepicker("setDate", new Date());


            $('#fechaFinal').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                language: 'es',
                updateViewDate: false
            });

            $("#fechaFinal").datepicker("setDate", new Date());

            console.log(data);
        });
```

Ahi esta el boton que llama a la función nuevo y tambien el editar.

Comment: Podrías añadir tu código que has estado trabajando para que podamos ayudarte?

Comment: Ahi esta el codigo espero ayude en algo con mi pregunta.

Comment: ps, tienes que borrarlos `$('#txtNumRUCModal').val("");` despues de modificar

Comment: si ya lo hice pero con el datepicker como seria limpiar? Me mostrarian un ejemplo solo me falta ello.